# Proof verification of equality of supports of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, modules, ideals

> Prove that if M is finitely generated module over $R$ then $\operatorname{Supp}(M/IM)=\operatorname{Supp}(M)\cap V(I)$.

First inclusion $\subseteq$ was easy and always right. My attempt at the second inclusion:

Assume $p\in\operatorname{Supp}(M)\cap V(I)$, therefore $I\subseteq p$ and $M_p\neq 0$. We want to prove that $(M/IM)_p\neq 0$. From properties of localization, $(M/IM)_p\simeq M_p/IM_p$. We assume by contradiction that $M_p/IM_p=0$. So $M_p=IM_p$. $M$ is finitely generated as a $R$ module, so $M_p$ is finitely generated as a $R_p$ module (this part I'm not sure about). Now, $I\subseteq p$ and therefore $I\subseteq pR_p$. So by Nakayama's lemma, $M_p=0$, but this is a contradiction.

I feel like everything I said is legit except for the argument where I concluded that $M_p$ is finitely generated as $R_p$ module. Is my proof correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If M is a finitely generated R-module and $S\subset R$ is a multiplicative set, then $S^{-1}M$ is a finitely generated $S^{-1}R$-module. Try to prove this. It's straightforward.

Comment: @user26857 Does this imply that my proof is ultimately correct?

Comment: Of course it is. (In fact, I'd replace $M_p=IM_p$ by $M_p=I_pM_p$.)